# ValueError: ('Could not interpret initializer identifier:', 0.2)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, python-3.5

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "AutoFC_AlexNet_randomsearch_CalTech101_v2.py", line 112, in 
>       X = layers.Dense(neurons, activation=activation, kernel_initializer=weight_init)(X)   File
>   "/home/shabbeer/NAS/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py",
>   line 91, in wrapper
>       return func(*args, **kwargs)   File "/home/shabbeer/NAS/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/layers/core.py",
>   line 824, in **init**
>       self.kernel_initializer = initializers.get(kernel_initializer)   File
>   "/home/shabbeer/NAS/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/initializers.py",
>   line 503, in get
>       identifier) ValueError: ('Could not interpret initializer identifier:', 0.2)

I am getting the above error when running the code using tensorflow-gpu version 1.4.0 and keras version 2.1.3

Comment: We can't tell you why you are getting this error unless you add some code here.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue with the He Unifrom initializer. I haven't found a solution yet: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69927838/specifying-a-weight-initialiser-returns-an-error-could-not-interpret-initialize

Answer (score 5):

you should change it to X = layers.Dense(neurons, activation=activation, kernel_initializer=keras.initializers.Constant(weight_init))(X)

Comment: I had to search a lot to find this solution. Thanks!

Comment: I'm having a similar problem with the he_uniform initialiser and this solution is not working. Could you look at my issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69927838/specifying-a-weight-initialiser-returns-an-error-could-not-interpret-initialize