# Specifying a weight initialiser returns an error: Could not interpret initializer identifier: 0

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, initializer

Why am I getting this error?

In one of the Dense layers I want to specify the HE Uniform weight initializer, like so:

```
Dense(64, input_shape=input_shape, kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.he_uniform())
```

And I get an error:
`ValueError: Could not interpret initializer identifier: 0`

When instead I specify it differently , like this:

```
kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.HeUniform()
```

I get a different error:
`module 'tensorflow_core.keras.initializers' has no attribute 'HeUniform'`

I am using the following imports:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as keras
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
```

What is wrong? And btw what is the difference between `HeUniform()` and `he_uniform()`?

Thanks

Comment: `HeUniform()` and `he_uniform()` are the same. I tried to reproduce your error but it worked fine for me. What is the value of the `input_shape` parameter?

Comment: The `input_shape` is `train_data[0].shape` which in my case is `(4,)`

Comment: I cannot reproduce this with your code. Are you sure you provided the line causing the error? Also which tensorflow version are you using? (output of `tf.__version__`)

Comment: My bad, the error was being caused by something else